# Windows Service Hosted TCP WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, wcf-client

I am trying to host a WCF service on a windows 2008 R2 server as a windows service. I followed the directions provided by msdn ([found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx)). Everything works fine as long as everything is part of the same solution in visual studio. However, I tried creating a client in a different solution (on the same machine) and it can't find the service. I get an 'Add Service Reference Error' shown below.

[image]

My goal is to be able to access the wcf service remotely, but I can't seem to even access it locally unless the client was created within the same client. Is there any guides, tutorials, or helpful hints that anyone can give me to get this to work?

**Update:**
It seems that even though the windows service is running, the WCF service doesn't seem to be listening to any ports. Which would suggest that it isn't running. This also explains why everyone's first thought I didn't have the service running. I had assumed that since the windows service was running and that the same solution client worked, that the WCF service was working as well. Turns out that Visual Studio was starting up a WCF service whenever I ran the same solution client.

So, why isn't the windows service starting the WCF service? Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the service running when trying to add the service reference?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, I had everything working that was explained in the tutorial, which includes starting the services.

Comment: Right, but did you have the service that you developed actually running when you tried adding the service reference from your new client?

Comment: Yes, i think it is fairly obvious that the service has to be running before I can connect to it or even pull metadata from it.

Comment: However, it might not be so obvious that the service was actually running. Turns out that the WCF service wasn't started even thought the windows service was. I don't know why nor how to fix it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that there was a problem with the tutorial provided by MSDN (provided in the question above). They named both the windows service and the WCF service `Service1` which is the default name for both of them.

The windows service was suppose to start the WCF service, however, it was actually trying to start itself again because both services had the same name.

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
```

To fix this problem, you can rename one of the services or fully qualify the WCF service when referenced in the windows service.

```
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1));
```

The funny thing is that the code provided still looks like it works because Visual Studio is smart enough to notice that the WCF service isn't running and it starts an instance up behind the scenes.

It was a simple bug to fix, but because Visual Studio was hiding the problem from me, I don't think I would have found it without the help from Espen Burud.

Comment: This resolved my (same) problem even if the two services (WCF and Windows Service) have had different names !!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways for Add Service Reference to learn about a service:

`Discover` button: searches the projects in the current solution.
`Go` button: connects to the service in the Address box and retrieves the metadata.

You need to actually have the service running before you click `Go`.

**EDIT**

I just noticed from your screenshot that you're trying to connect to a net.tcp URL. I think it's more common to use http for MEX. Your app.config would look something like:

```xml
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior"
    name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8524/Service1" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Note the different port number for the http base address. You would then use "http://localhost:8524/Service1" in the Add Service Reference tool. You should also be able to connect to it with your web browser.

To allow metadata exchange via http GET (e.g. from a browser), you also need to enable it via a behavior:

```xml
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I'm not sure if the Add Service Reference tool cares about that.

Even if you don't want to allow http get access (httpGetEnabled="False"), you still need to include this behavior to enable MEX (unless you're adding it programatically).

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but it doesn't really help my issue.

Comment: The tutorial that I referenced above has you utilize metadata exchange through tcp without adding a http base address. I suppose I can try adding a http base address to see if it works, but I don't really want to give access to the service over http.

Comment: I've never done this, but here's an example of exposing MEX via TCP: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/exposing-a-metadata-exchange-mex-endpoint-over-tcp-with-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service.aspx

Comment: For http, you might need to include the serviceMetadata behavior, see my last edit. I looked at the tutorial you referenced and it has httpGetEnabled set to false (which prevents access to metadata by http GET, fairly obviously).

Comment: It has been confirmed that I don't need to mess with HTTP. I can achieve everything with TCP, but I haven't quite figured out how to do it yet (see Espen's answer) I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the MSDN article in the and it works without modifications. If the firewall is enabled on the server, I think you will need to add some rules for your service.

To verify that the service are listening on the correct tcp port, you can use command: `netstat -a`. If the service are listening on the correct port, this command will return:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:8523           machinename:0          LISTENING
```

Comment: I have it working without modification as well. However, it creates the client within the same solution. If I try to create the client outside the same solution of the services, it can't connect to the service even though its on the same machine and the services are running fine.

Comment: It works for me, also when I created the client in a separate solution.

Comment: So, I tried the `netstat` command that you suggested and noticed that even though the windows service is running, the wcf service doesn't seem to be running. Did you have this same problem? What could be my problem?

Comment: @BryanWatts: does the user that the service runs under have permission to use the port? If not you will need to create an ACL or run the service with elevated permissions.

Comment: It has permission. I ended up figuring out the main problem with help from you answer. See my answer for full details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the issue.  My service didn't know about the endpoints because I hadn't copied the service configuration from the app.config in the WCF project into the app.config of the actual windows service.  Once I did that it functioned correctly.

This was not made clear in the original MSDN article which I had also followed although it is mentioned in a comment in the WCF app.config.