# WCF hosted in Windows service via TCP - can't consume

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I just spend 4 hours googling around trying to find why i cant consume (add service reference) WCF hosted in Windows service. Error i am getting is this

> The URI prefix is not recognized.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1'.
>   Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0158574. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523. 
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I created a small service following this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx to the letter. I'm stuck on step 8 where i get error i posted above.

My App.config (WCF configuration)

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings />
  <services>
    <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="netTcpEndpoint" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="mexTCPendpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />
        </baseAddresses>
        <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" />
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"
          includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service.1.cs

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    internal static ServiceHost MyServiceHost = null;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (MyServiceHost != null)
        {
            MyServiceHost.Close();
        }

        MyServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
        MyServiceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (MyServiceHost != null)
        {
            MyServiceHost.Close();
            MyServiceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Turning off windows firewall
- Opening port TCP 8523 (in and outbound rules)
- Changing port numbers
- Checking netstat -atn (TCP port 8523 is not listnening)
- Double checking that serviceProcessInstaller1 has account option set to Network service
- Double checking that serviceInstaller1 has StartType option set to Automatic
- Double checking that Service1 is Started in services.msc
- Enabled all Net.XXX Services in services.msc
- Remove then Added TCP Activation and TCP Port Sharing in "Turn windows features on or off"
- Ran out of ideas

Any help as to why i can't consume WCF is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does network service have the right priveleges to register the service URL?  Take a look at your Event Viewer and see if there's any errors in there regarding unable to register the URL.

Comment: Your config slightly differs from the one from msdn. For example, you've got  address="" for mex-endpoint, whereas the example has address="mex". With this little change I was able to add service reference to msdn service with your config. I also used Console application as a host to make it simpler to run and debug.

Comment: The right answer for this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193847/windows-service-hosted-tcp-wcf-service